# Parsing/scraping issue with simplehtmldom

Tags: php, parsing, screen-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to use simplehtmldom to parse a web page with many li tags.

I'd like to only extract the innertext for the specific tag `<li class='ev_td_li c5'>` that occurs in the following snippet:

```
<li class='ev_td_li c5'>10:00  
    <a class="ev_link_row c3" href="/fr/quoi-faire-a-sutton/programme-activites-sutton/calendrier-hebdomadaire/icalrepeat.detail/2012/01/01/13918/-/NTNkZDVjNzNiNzE1YTBmM2VhZjMyZjljNmU0ODFiNjQ=.html"
        title="Marche du 2012">Marche du 2012</a>::  
    <a class="ev_link_cat c4" href="/fr/quoi-faire-a-sutton/programme-activites-sutton/calendrier-hebdomadaire/week.listevents/2012/01/02/122.html"
        title="Outdoor, Sporting Events ">Outdoor, Sporting Events</a>
</li>
```

If I use the following code I get all the 'li' tags:

```
foreach($html->find('li') as $e){
 echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
```

But if I try to add the class as in the following I don't get any output:

```
foreach($html->find('li.ev_td_li c5') as $e){
    echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
```

I'm wondering if the space char in 'li.ev_td_li c5' is the problem.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks
Elliot

Answer (score 0):

Try `li.ev_td_li.c5` (note the `.` in front of the c5) instead. If you have `'li.ev_td_li c5` (note the space), it's interpreted as "a `<li>` tag of class ev_td_li, followed by a `<c5>` tag".

Comment: I tried `foreach($html->find('li.ev_td_li.c5') as $e)` and am still getting not getting any  output :-(

Comment: simplehtml may not support multiple selectors on a single tag. You might have to upgrade to using the full DOM setup instead.

Comment: Just tried: `foreach($html->find('li.ev_td_li') as $e)` and it's giving an acceptable output. I didn't see any references to this at [http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm] . Is there any other documentation that describes this kind of behaviour?